# Error in as.vector(x, mode) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any' -- when running a nested function

Tags: r, function, matrix, vector, nested-function

Problem: running `get_pi_ij()` gives the error:

`Error in as.vector(x, mode) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'`

`Called from: as.vector(data)`

The first thing this function does is to make the resulting `alphas` and `beta_prelims` into matrixes that match `c` so that they can be calculated together. This is where something goes wrong, and I have not been able to figure out what. If I use `<<-` to save the `alphas` and `betas` to the global environment in the prior functions for alphas and betas and replace that with those in the faulty function, it works. So I assume it has to do with how I call the functions inside the matrix creation.

```
get_pi_ij <- function() {
  alphas <-
    matrix(get_alpha(),
           nrow = length(get_alpha()),
           ncol = length(get_alpha()),
           byrow = FALSE)
  betas <-
    matrix(get_beta_prelim,
           nrow = length(get_beta_prelim()),
           ncol = length(get_beta_prelim()),
           byrow = TRUE) 
  pi_ij <- exp(alphas + betas + gamma * c)
  return(pi_ij)
}
get_pi_ij()
```

I added the full code cause it's not too long and the first parts are just definitions. Makes it easier to test it.

**Everything up to the final function works as it is supposed to**

```
size <- 18 
gamma <- -0.07 

c <- structure(c(0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 4, 4, 8, 12, 16, 8, 8, 8, 12, 16, 
            12, 12, 16, 16, 4, 0, 4, 8, 12, 8, 4, 4, 8, 12, 12, 8, 8, 12, 
            16, 12, 12, 16, 16, 8, 4, 0, 4, 8, 12, 8, 4, 8, 12, 16, 12, 8, 
            12, 16, 16, 12, 16, 16, 12, 8, 4, 0, 4, 12, 8, 4, 4, 8, 16, 12, 
            8, 8, 12, 16, 12, 12, 16, 16, 12, 8, 4, 0, 16, 12, 8, 4, 4, 16, 
            12, 8, 8, 8, 16, 12, 12, 16, 4, 8, 12, 12, 16, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 
            4, 4, 8, 12, 16, 8, 8, 12, 12, 4, 4, 8, 8, 12, 4, 0, 4, 8, 12, 
            8, 4, 4, 8, 12, 8, 8, 12, 12, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 4, 0, 4, 8, 12, 
            8, 4, 8, 12, 12, 8, 12, 12, 12, 8, 8, 4, 4, 12, 8, 4, 0, 4, 12, 
            8, 4, 4, 8, 12, 8, 8, 12, 16, 12, 12, 8, 4, 16, 12, 8, 4, 0, 
            16, 12, 8, 4, 4, 12, 8, 8, 12, 8, 12, 16, 16, 16, 4, 8, 12, 12, 
            16, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 4, 8, 12, 8, 8, 8, 12, 12, 12, 4, 4, 8, 
            8, 12, 4, 0, 4, 8, 12, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 
            8, 8, 4, 0, 4, 8, 8, 4, 8, 8, 12, 12, 12, 8, 8, 12, 8, 8, 4, 
            4, 12, 8, 4, 0, 4, 8, 4, 4, 8, 16, 16, 16, 12, 8, 16, 12, 12, 
            8, 4, 16, 12, 8, 4, 0, 12, 8, 4, 8, 12, 12, 16, 16, 16, 8, 8, 
            12, 12, 12, 4, 4, 8, 8, 12, 0, 4, 8, 4, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 8, 
            8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 0, 4, 4, 16, 16, 16, 12, 12, 12, 
            12, 12, 8, 8, 12, 8, 8, 4, 4, 8, 4, 0, 4, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
            12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 0), 
          .Dim = c(19L, 19L), 
          .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", 
                                   "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", 
                                   "X11", "X12", "X13", "X14", "X15", 
                                   "X16", "X17", "X18", "X19")))

set.seed(12345) 
h_share <- diff(c(0, sort(runif(size)), 1)) 
e_share <- diff(c(0, sort(runif(size)), 1)) 

alpha <- numeric(size + 1)
beta <- numeric(size + 1)

get_beta_prelim <- function() {
  a_matrix <- exp(alpha + t(c) * gamma)
  beta_prelim <- log(e_share) - log(colSums(a_matrix))
  return(beta_prelim)
}

get_beta <- function() {
  beta <- get_beta_prelim() - get_beta_prelim()[[1]]
  return(beta)
}

get_alpha_prelim <- function() {
  b_matrix <- t(exp(beta + t(c) * gamma))
  alpha_prelim <- log(h_share) - log(rowSums(b_matrix))
  return(alpha_prelim)
}

get_alpha <- function() {
  alpha <- get_alpha_prelim() - get_alpha_prelim()[[1]]
  return(alpha)
}

get_pi_ij <- function() {
  alphas <-
    matrix(get_alpha(),
           nrow = length(get_alpha()),
           ncol = length(get_alpha()),
           byrow = FALSE)
  betas <-
    matrix(get_beta_prelim,
           nrow = length(get_beta_prelim()),
           ncol = length(get_beta_prelim()),
           byrow = TRUE) 
  pi_ij <- exp(alphas + betas + gamma * c)
  return(pi_ij)
}
get_pi_ij()
```

Comment: Any packages needed? I don't recognize `get_alpha`

Comment: @markhogue it's a function that I create. You can see it in the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
get_pi_ij <- function() {
  alphas <-
    matrix(get_alpha(),
           nrow = length(get_alpha()),
           ncol = length(get_alpha()),
           byrow = FALSE)
  betas <-
    matrix(get_beta_prelim(), # your were missing "()"
           nrow = length(get_beta_prelim()),
           ncol = length(get_beta_prelim()),
           byrow = TRUE) 
  pi_ij <- exp(alphas + betas + gamma * c)
  return(pi_ij)
}
```

Comment: So simple! How did I not see that. Thank you.